# Linq query to update values based on another column

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq

How can I update column based on another column value matchings.for example.

Input table has only column a and b
I want to create column c and update value based on column a.if a has word error column c should be failed. If it has success then c should also be success.

Similarly column d should be created based on values of column b

How can I achieve this with linq as I have hundreds of thousands of records

Output :

```
Colum A.  column B column c column d
No error. Router.   Failed.  Network
Error.    Switch.   Failed.   Network
Success.  App.    Success. Application
```

Comment: Please don't use words like "lakh" / "lac" here since we who don't live in India don't use or understand them.

Comment: Which LINQ provider do you use? EF Core?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table model class looks something like:

```
public class Model
{
    public string ColumnA { get; set; }
    public string ColumnB { get; set; }
    public string ColumnC { get; set; }
    public string ColumnD { get; set; }
}
```

and you have declared the table as:

```
List<Model> table;
//Initialize list, with column A and column B values entered/initialized
```

and you have defined following variable:

```
var NetworkKeys = new List<string> {"router", "switch"};
```

Then using linq foreach (you can also use normal foreach) and if..else, you can get set values of column c and d as:

```
table.ForEach(a =>
    {
        if(a.ColumnA.ToLower().Contains("error"))
            a.ColumnC = "Failed";
        else if(a.ColumnA.ToLower().Contains("success"))
            a.ColumnC = "Success";

        if(NetworkKeys.Contains(a.ColumnB.ToLower()))
            a.ColumnD = "Network";
        else if(a.ColumnB.ToLower().Contains("app"))
            a.ColumnD = "Application";
    });
```